# How to automatically update model field if there are changes to the previous field?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to find a way to update the latest field in a model if there are changes in the earlier field.

for example: say I have a Cash Balance model

[image: Cash Balance]

If I change the sale inv 134 debits to 50. how do I make this change reflect on the other cash balance coming after it automatically?

Edit 1 :

```
class AccountsModel(models.Model):

Date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
INV_No = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
Discription = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,default=0.0)
Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,default=0.0)
CashBalance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,default=0.0)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

@property
def GetLastCB(self):
    return AccountsModel.objects.last().CashBalance

def get_bookno(self):
    if not self.INV_No:
        return ''
    return self.INV_No
```

This is a simple model that I made. I made API views to GET, POST AND DELETE

Comment: Please add the source code you have. A minimal, reproducible Example is needed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to use is a signal

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=CashBalance)
def update_cash_balance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.balance != instance.calculate_balance()
        instance.set_balance()
```

Be wary of using .save() within the signal because you can start a recursive loop, put an if-statement check to prevent this from happening

Comment: Due to lack of code, your question is hard to understand fully. But the way I would approach this given that I could access the old object will be to 1) save the old objects in session, 2) grab hold of the new object, 3) compare both field for difference 4) # do your thing here... 5) save new object or maybe create a custom signal to  send a notification that this object old value has changed.